# Android Studio "Unable to merge dex"

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-multidex

I keep getting this error. I cleaned everything, build, Rebuild, jumbomode, MultidexApplication I tried everything as possible I can, but everything didn't work out.

Sometimes it is necessary to remove the dependency one by one, but now it is useless.

I got stuck on this error from this error more than a week. anybody knows how to fix it out?

There's my config files below.

**app.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 6
        versionName "1.0.5"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        /*manifestPlaceholders = [ onesignal_app_id: "",
                                 onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE" ]*/

        manifestPlaceholders = [
                manifestApplicationId          : "${applicationId}",
                onesignal_app_id               : "",
                onesignal_google_project_number: ""
        ]
    }
    dexOptions {
//        jumboMode true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
//    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // one signal
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.7.1@aar'
    // zendesk
    implementation 'com.zendesk:sdk:1.10.0.1'
    implementation('com.zendesk:sdk:1.10.0.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    // UnifyID
    implementation 'id.unify.sdk:sdk:0.8.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    // circle ImageView
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    // fabric
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    // fitChart
    implementation 'com.txusballesteros:FitChart:1.0'
    // retrofit2
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    // google play services(google fit, google map, location)
    //noinspection GradleCompatible,UseOfBundledGooglePlayServices
//    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
//    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
//    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.8.0'
    // firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    // facebook
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.25.0'
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.1'
    // glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.5.0'
}
```

**project.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

//apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
//apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        //maven { url "https://artifacts.unify.id" }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'

        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
//        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.22.1'
        //classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:latest.release"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            url "http://gradle.unify.id/artifactory/gradle-release"
            credentials {
                username = ""
                password = ""
            }
        }
        maven { url 'https://zendesk.jfrog.io/zendesk/repo' }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }

        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: have clicked in FIle = > restart and invalidate cache

Comment: [Add an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Remario I already tried and didn't work out.

Comment: I think the last this happened some cyclic dependency was there, had to use exclude

Comment: @Remario What do you mean by cyclic dependency? what does it actually mean?

Answer (score -1):

Try the different version combinations of `gms:play-services:X.X.X` library and also try by adding this code in your **app module** `build.gradle` file

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
       multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the versions of google-play service library?

Answer (score -1):

If u overridinig your Application class you need to do this

```
public class MyApplication extends SomeOtherApplication {
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
 super.attachBaseContext(base);
 MultiDex.install(this);
 }
}
```

if that is  not the case than u should in your manifest file in your application tag add this

```
 <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
    ...
</application>
```

Hope this will help you,in my app I have multidex and everything is working fine.

Comment: I just saw you are using firebase and facebook so you will need to overide libraries something like this  <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.firebase.ui,com.firebase.ui.auth,com.facebook" /> in manifest

Comment: did you try it ?

Comment: I also have this in my project                                                               
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
//
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.0'
            }
        }
    }                                  bellow dependecies in app gradle